# How can I use a fork of react-admin (or one of its packages) in my production environment?

Tags: npm, react-admin, lerna

I need a few changes to the ra-core package of the react-admin monorepo on my productive environment.

Can I tell a lerna published module to use my own published module as a submodule instead of it's own?

It's about this package:
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-admin

I'm about to create a PR to maybe have these changes merged into the project itself, but I can't know when it will be merged and / or whether it will be even accepted.

But unfortunately I need these changes immediately and it's okay for me to use a fork of mine until it's clear what happens to the PR.

I tried to fork a new ra-core package and use this in my package.json, but this doesn't work. Locally linking is no problem, as I can link it directly in the react-admin module, but I need it in my production build process.

So I'm wondering if there is some way to tell the module in my package.json (react-admin) which comes with it's own subpackages to use one package that I provide in the package.json instead of it's subpackage.

Comment: Did you try yarn resolutions? https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/